# Profiling in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializr, using embedded Tomcat + Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used :

Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE, Thymeleaf 2.1.5.RELEASE, Tomcat Embed 8.5.6, Maven 3, Java 8

I have this class

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping({ "/", "/tdk/login"})
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        return "tdk/login";
    }
}

 and this other one:

@Profile("pebloc")
public class PeblocLoginController extends LoginController {

    @Override
    @RequestMapping({ "/", "/pebloc/login"})
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        return "pebloc/login";
    }
}
```

I am running my SpringBoot in Eclipse app with this VM arguments

```
-DAPP-KEY=pebloc -Dspring.profiles.active=pebloc
```

but PeblocLoginController is not loaded !

2017-03-05 17:

```
29:01.617  INFO 20189 --- [  restartedMain] c.i.iot.TDKCloudApplication           : The following profiles are active: pebloc

    17-03-05 09:35:12.689  INFO 2190 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/ || /tdk/login]}" onto public java.lang.String com.tdk.web.LoginController.welcome(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to annotate `PeblocLoginController` with `@Controller`. `@Controller` is not an inherited annotation. It will be like this:

```
@Profile("pebloc")
@Controller
public class PeblocLoginController extends LoginController {

    @Override
    @RequestMapping({ "/", "/pebloc/login"})
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        return "pebloc/login";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Controller` or `@RestController` annotation with PeblocLoginController class depending on requirement as they indicate that the class is ready to be used to handle web requests.

PS: Consider using [Spring Tool Suite](https://spring.io/tools/sts/all) while developing Spring Boot Applications.